# PHP require failing even though is_file and is_readable works using absolute paths

Tags: php, require

I was having issues with another piece of code so I broke out this very simple part and put it in a new file:

Test file Location/Name

> /var/www/html/php/tst/test.php

Test file Content

```
<?php

if(is_readable('/var/www/html/php/put/json_load.php')){echo('Worked');}
if(is_readable('/var/www/html/php/put/cr_query.php')){echo('Worked2');}
if(is_readable('/var/www/html/php/put/json_crdata_decode.php')){echo('Worked3');}

require '/var/www/html/php/put/json_load.php';

echo('Worked4');

?>
```

The output I get from this is

> WorkedWorked2Worked3

It seems to be stopping execution at require. I am fairly new to PHP, and have searched long and hard for a solution. Any help is appreciated.

If any more information is needed I'd be glad to provide it.

Comment: I don't see why `echo('Worked4');` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three possibilities:

- json_load.php stop script execution by calling exit() or die()
- json_load.php triggers an error. Your display_error is set to 0 so
  you experience no feedback
- segmentation fault

I suspect option 2. Edit your php.ini and set display_errors to 1 then restart the server. If you don't know where php.ini is run phpinfo() funciton, it will tell you.

Comment: Editing php.ini to show errors is perfect. I was unaware! It was in fact, the entire time, a missing semi-colon in json_load.php. Thank you for the information!